# Convert date with format Jan 1, 2023 to 01/01/2023 format

Tags: r, date, format

I have a vector containing a set of dates with Month day, Year (Jan 1, 2023) format. I need to convert the dates to DD/MM/YY (01/01/2023) format using R language.

How can I do it?

```
my_dates <- c("Jan 1, 2023", "Jan 2, 2023", "Feb 1, 2023", "Feb 2, 2023")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
my_dates <- c("Jan 1, 2023", "Jan 2, 2023", "Feb 1, 2023", "Feb 2, 2023")
lubridate::mdy(my_dates) |> format("%d/%m/%Y")
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "01/01/2023" "02/01/2023" "01/02/2023" "02/02/2023"
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `date` and `format` it. Check `?strptime` for more information about date formatting:

```r
as.Date(my_dates, format = "%b %d, %Y") |>
  format("%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "01/01/2023" "02/01/2023" "01/02/2023" "02/02/2023"
```